# How disable war plugin for specific project

Tags: gradle

I have following lines in my main build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'war'
}
```

But I'd like to disable war building for specific project. How to achieve that?
I had tried to overwrite task in project config but didn't succeeded.

```
task war(type: War, overwrite: true) << {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's better to apply the plugin to the right projects in the first place, rather than trying to undo its effects later. For example:

```
configure(subprojects - project(":specific")) {
   apply plugin: "war"
}
```

Alternatively, you could push down application of the plugin to (some of) the subprojects' build scripts.

Comment: The war plug-in has useful property "providedCompile". So I can just add config once for all projects.

Comment: You'd have to explain in more detail what exactly you are trying to achieve. There is no such thing as "disabling a plugin"; the closest thing is not to apply it (as shown above). If all you want is to prevent the `war` *task* from running, it's as simple as `war.enabled = false`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way it can be accomplished:

Instead of this:

```
subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'war'
```

This:

```
subprojects {


    if (!project.name.equals("MySpecificProjectName")) {
      apply plugin: 'war'
    }
```