# In a multi-module Gradle project, how do I skip a plugin defined in the parent?

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-module Gradle project with n subprojects written in Java, and one non-Java web subproject, as follows:

```
parent
- service1
.
.
- serviceN
- web
```

In my parent `build.gradle`, I define plugins as follows:

```
plugins {
    id: 'whatever'
}
```

In my all of my subprojects except one, I want use the `whatever` plugin.  But in my `web` subproject, I want to exclude the `whatever` plugin since that subproject is not written in Java.  How do I skip a plugin in a subproject?

In Maven, I can do this by redefining the plugin in the `<plugins>` section of the module's pom and setting the `<skip>` tag to true.

How do I do something similar to this in the latest version of Gradle (at time of writing, 7.4.2)?  Note that I want to configure whether the plugin is skipped **in the child subproject**, not in the parent project.

Comment: How is the `java` plugin being applied to the `web` project? You need to at least provide samples of your Gradle build files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How disable war plugin for specific project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018655/how-disable-war-plugin-for-specific-project)

If you don't want a plugin applied to a project, simply don't apply it.

Comment: I don't understand the first comment.  In Gradle 7.4, all that is needed to apply a plugin is to define it in the manner shown above.  By default, subprojects inherit the plugins defined in the parent's build.gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gradle subprojects, a plugin declared in the `plugins` block in the parent's `build.gradle` can be disabled/skipped in the child by adding `apply false` to the child project's `build.gradle` plugins configuration.  In this case, that would look like:

```
plugins {
    id 'whatever' apply false
}
```